# TSM AdjustCapsLockLEDForKeyTransitionHandling - _ISSetPhysicalKeyboardCapsLockLED Inhibit

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, apple-m1

---

### Python: 3.9.5
Os: macOS 11.4

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
e1_value = StringVar()


def printText():
    print(e1_value.get())
# def printText():
#     print('HelloWorld!')

b1 = Button(window, text = "Excute", command = printText())
b1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

e1 = Entry(window, textvariable = e1_value)
e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

t1 = Text(window, height = 1, width = 20)
t1.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

window.mainloop()
```

I met an error that was printed out in the terminal so I couldn't print out the value into the terminal. The error said,

> "TSM AdjustCapsLockLEDForKeyTransitionHandling -
> _ISSetPhysicalKeyboardCapsLockLED Inhib"

, when I type something into Entry window. I've been searching for the answer on Google, but I still can't find it.  Do you happen to know how to solve the problem?

Besides, I could see 'Hellow world!' only once even if I pushed the Button a few times.

I'm not acquainted with tkinter so I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the parenthesis after printText.
`b1 = Button(window, text = "Excute", command = printText)`

I could print out what I typed in the Entry box. I still saw "TSM AdjustCapsLockLEDForKeyTransitionHandling - _ISSetPhysicalKeyboardCapsLockLED Inhib" though.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
e1_value = StringVar()

def printText():
 print(e1_value.get())
# def printText():
#     print('HelloWorld!')

b1 = Button(window, text = "Excute", command = printText)
b1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

e1 = Entry(window, textvariable = e1_value)
e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

t1 = Text(window, height = 1, width = 20)
t1.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have another language in your keyboard preferences.

Delete the language that is not english in your keyboard preferences

Answer (score 0):

If you are a macOS user, enter system preferences/keyboard/input sources
in the bottom of the screen disable the second option or delete input sources except english.